# Sonar maven plugin unable to parse groovy files

Tags: sonarqube-scan

My project module has java and groovy files in `src/java` and `src/groovy` folder accordingly.

When I run maven sonar analysis on jenkin , I get following error message. I don't know why sonar maven plugin not able to parse groovy files.

> [ERROR] [12:59:29.878] Unable to parse source file : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/eceweb Sonar Analysis/java-component/src/test/groovy/com/gab/AbcdIT.groovy
>   [ERROR] [12:59:29.878] Parse error at line 3 column 1:

My Code:

```
 1: package com.gab
 2: 
 3: import com.abc.application.SpockTransactionManager
    ^
 4:
 7: import org.junit.Ignore
 8: 
 9: class AbcdIT extends SpockTransactionManager {
10:     FeatureToggleDaoTestBuilder testBuilder
11: 
12:     def setup() {
13:         testBuilder = SpringBeanContext.getBean(FeatureToggleDaoTestBuilder.class)
```